# How to stop executing code after setVisible of JWindow until it is closed?

Tags: java, swing, jwindow

For example, I have code like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JWindow w = new JWindow();
    w.setSize(100, 100);
    w.setVisible(true);
    // some code need to be executed after window is closed, Eg.
    System.out.println("some code need to be executed after window is closed");
}
```

I want code to stop at `w.setVisible(true);` until the window is closed/setVisible(false), then execute `System.out.println("window closed");`, how to achieve this?

Comment: Go back to docs, learn about Window listeners management.

Comment: I know listener, but here what I asked is how to pause code execution until window is closed. For now, the 'System.out.println("window closed");' will be continued executing even the window is open.

Comment: If you move that S.o.p to the listener, when you click close window, that code will run. Another alternative is to add JVM shutdown hooks, but this is overkill if you ask me.

Comment: You need to use a modal JDialog

Comment: `JOptionPane` to the rescue

Answer (score 0):

you could refer to this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html)

you can override the `windowClosing()` method

```
public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
  System.out.println("window closed");
}
```

or windowClosed()

```
public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
  System.out.println("window closed");
}
```

based on what you are doing, right after the `setVisible(true)` start the screen capture in your constructor for example, and then the screen capture should tell you that the process is done so you can proceed to your other code execution. there is no need to pause the code execution.

Comment: There is certainly a misunderstanding here, what I really want is to pause code execution after `setVisible(true)`, not print 'window closed'.

Comment: why do you want to pause the execution after setVisible(true) what is the story behind that

Comment: @JianweiLiu the only other choice you gave is to use a JDialog

Comment: I am doing a screen capture program using the Java JWindow, after screen shot is captured, i.e. part of the JWindow is captured, then continue with following code. This is called from Eclipse plugin.

Comment: you should do something like setVisible(true) > check if JWindow capture is done then execute the code. you dont need to pause the code execution.

Answer (score -1):

You can use window closing event or window closed event

```
 public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) 
 {
        System.out.println("window closed");
 }
```

OR

```
  public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) 
  {
         System.out.println("window closed");
  }
```

Comment: Did you just copy and paste @Kerppag code? How does this add anything to or differ from an answer that was answered more than an hour before this one?